# ViewData not displaying content in View (asp.net mvc c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4 C# and I'm facing a problem with displaying an array in my View:

I'd like to display a number of error messages from my controller to the view, but so far, the content of only 1 array is displayed...

Only the data in "ViewData["mededelingen"] is displayed. The data in ViewData["warnings"] is not displayed, despite the same code.

**Below is the code of the view:**

[image]

When I debugged, I have noticed that the ViewData["warnings"] is not empty, **as shown in the next screenshot**:

[image]

However, it does **not** display the contents on my HTML page.

**Below is the output:**

[image]

As you can see, only the items in red (mededelingen) are displayed, the items in yellow (warnings) are not.

**Below is the code of the controller:**

[image]

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what exactly...
Any help?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why insert your code as screenshots when SO has syntax highlighting?

Comment: can you make sure that it really doesn't print anything into your html markup? Just examine the html source of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisplayName` gets the display attribute of the model property represented by the string that's passed to it. Since your string is just a sentence, that doesn't make sense. Why are you using `DisplayName` at all?

Just do:

```
@foreach (var counter2 in (ViewData["warnings"] as List<string>))
{
    <td>@counter2</td>
}
```